# how to remove result popup from square reader sdk

Tags: ios, square-connect, square

[image]

how to disable this square pop up after the transaction. I'm using In-Person Payment option from Square Reader SDK for iOS

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no way to remove the pop-up at this time. That part of the UI is built-in and not customizable via ReaderSDK.